# php calling parent function makes parent unable to load own vars

Tags: php, class, parent, parent-child

I have a Handler class that looks like this:

```
class Handler{
    public $group;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->group = $this->database->mysql_fetch_data("blabla query");
        //if i print_r($this->group) here it gives proper result

        new ChildClass();
    }

    public function userGroup(){
        print_r($this->group); //this is empty
                    return $this->group;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends Handler{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->userGroup();
        //i tried this too
        parent::userGroup();
        //userGroup from parent always returns empty
    }

}
```

Workflow:

- Handler is called from my index.php and the __construct is called
- Handler needs to create $group
- Handler creates child class
- Child class calls Handler function
- When I try to return $group in the function It tries to get $this->group from Child instead of Handler

Whenever I try to ask the parent something I can only access the parent function then inside the function the parent class can't find any of it's own variables

EDIT:

I figured using 'extends' would be useful in calling parent functions but it seems just passing $this on to the child will be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never called the parent constructor, so the group object is never initialized. You will want to do something like this.

```
class Handler{
    public $group;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->group = $this->database->mysql_fetch_data("blabla query");
        //if i print_r($this->group) here it gives proper result

        new ChildClass();
    }

    public function userGroup(){
        print_r($this->group); //this is empty
                    return $this->group;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends Handler{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->userGroup();
    }

}
```

If you had *not* overwritten the __construct method in your extended class, then the parent __construct would have automatically been called, but since you overwrote it in the extended class, you must tell it to call the parent's __construct in your extended class' __construct.

Comment: Or maybe he wants `public $group` to be static and not actually have two different objects. :p

Comment: @Basti either way, he has to do the above, and since he didn't mention what you are talking about, I'm not sure why you bring it up.

Comment: If i do this the parent calls on the child again and there is a endless loop

Comment: @Basti If i make it static it says Notice: Undefined property: ChildClass::$group

Comment: I'm bringing it up as an extension to your answer. No harm done.

Comment: @Makura You need to make some more changes if you want `$group` to be static. You are also missing some initialisation statements like `new Handler()`. It's not clear what you are trying to do just from your class definition.

Comment: Edited post, New Handler() is done in index, i asumed you would expect handler to be called since i stated that inside handler construct $this->group is filled

Comment: @dqhendricks I have looked though php.net extends page but could not find a solution, and i use the handler class to call many difrent classes depending on what page i'm on. and i find it usefull to be able to use functions of the Handler class everywhere, If there is a other solution to achieve that it would work too.

Comment: @MakuraYami oy. you may want to read up on Agile development, Single Responsibility Principle, Dependency Injection, Composition over Inheritance.